# Resize Images, Fixed Positions

Tags: css, image, resize, position

I want to keep those banners positions fixed. And make them resizable. Because on the smaller monitors, banners goes wherever they want. And they always stay bigger than the background.   If you resize the browser you can see what i'm trying to tell.

http://mecanik.net/theback/5/index_1.html

```
.tab1{background-image:url(../images/tab1.PNG); width:302px;
height:201px; background-repeat:no-repeat; display:block;
position:absolute; top:18%; left:5%;}
```

Comment: Unrelated comment: not a good idea to play music on a site without user specifically telling you to.

Comment: they wanted music especially :)

Answer (score 0):

Since their parent div is the background, which already resizes, you can set the image sizes to a percentage of it. Percentage heights and widths are of their parent container, so something like %15 should do it. Since you're displaying them as backgrounds of their container, you'll need to use the css background-size attribute.

Keep in mind that background-size will work in just about everything except IE 8 and earlier IE versions.

Set the background of .tab1 to be images/tab1.PNG. Remove the html img tags, and try adding the code below to .tab1 in your css. You'll have to play with the percentages a bit, but it should start making things scale.

```
    background: url(../images/tab1.png); background-size: 100% auto; height:20%; width:30%;
```

Comment: http://mecanik.net/theback/5/index_1.html  ... O couldnt do what you said. I tried everway. Can you explain a little bit please. Is there another way? Thank you so much.

Comment: Heey, Please i'm waiting heeeeeeeeeeeeeelp :)